# Using Install4j v 10.04 Delete Files and Folders Action to Delete unknown number of files

Tags: windows, install4j

Can I use the "Delete Files and Directories" action to delete all files with a specific extension. The directory is an installer variable and then I would like to do something like "*.txt" in that directory to delete all files of that type in the given directory.

I am trying to delete all files with a "*.txt" extension in a specified folder.

I tried specifying ${installer.FileFolder}*.txt in the Files and directories field in the action and it took it literally and did not understand the wildcard character.

So then I tried specifying ${installer.FileFolder} in the Files and directories field and file.getName.endsWith(".txt") in the File filter script field.  This still did not work and just seemed to ignore what was in the File filter field.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the "File filter script" property of the "Delete files and directories" action to something like

```
file.getName().endsWith(".txt")
```

to only delete files with a particular extension.